# Does predictive mean matching (pmm) in the package MICE only use rows without any missing data to estimate his coefficients?

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I have a dataframe which contains the abundance of different plants over 5 successive years (1 value per year; from T2 to T6) for different sites(15 sites) and treatments(browsed vs unbrowsed). T2 to T6 are in columns and I have one column specifying the species.

For some sites, T5 is systematically missing. For the rest of the sites, T4 and T6 are both missing. T2 and T3 are available for all sites.

Here is a fictive example of what it looks like:

```
> data = matrix(c(0.02, 0.02, 0.03, NA, 0.06,
+               0.01, 0.04, NA, 0.03, NA,
+               0.11, 0.12, 0.14, NA, 0.19,
+               0.06, 0.04, NA, 0, NA,
+               0.22, 0.26, 0.34, NA, 0.46),5,5, byrow=TRUE)
> colnames(data) = c("T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6")
> data = as.data.frame(data)
> data$species = c("Abibal", "Abibal", "Abibal", "Rubida", "Rubida")
> data
    T2   T3   T4   T5   T6 species
1 0.02 0.02 0.03   NA 0.06  Abibal
2 0.01 0.04   NA 0.03   NA  Abibal
3 0.11 0.12 0.14   NA 0.19  Abibal
4 0.06 0.04   NA 0.00   NA  Rubida
5 0.22 0.26 0.34   NA 0.46  Rubida
```

Consequently, there is no row which doesn't contain any NA.

Since data are systematically missing but that the chance of being missing is not linked to the data value, I consider that the data are Missing At Random (MAR).

Now, I would like to use mice() and predictive mean matching to impute my missing data. I ran it a first time and encountered no error. However, when carefully looking at the imputed data, I encountered some weird imputed data.

While trying to better understand the mechanics behind predictive mean matching, I read that the function start by estimating a linear regression for cases with no missing data.

Does that means that the function only uses rows without missing data to estimate his coefficients ? Or that when, for example, the function try to impute values for T5, it only uses rows which have no missing data for T5 to estimate his coefficients?

Also, how does the function take into account qualitative variables (like "species") when estimating his coefficients? Does it estimate coefficients for each value of "species" individually ?

Any help on the matter, or on what would be the best way to impute data in my case are appreciated.

Thank ou very much,

Laurent